# How to remove middle substring using regex?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I turn this string `....cid=1234;tld=...` to `....cid=;tld=...`

I have tried this formula unsuccessfully:

```
=REGEXREPLACE( A1, "(.*cid=)(.*)(;tld=.*)", "$1$3"));
```

How should I remove the middle substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "(.+cid=)(.+)(;tfua=.+)"; "$1$3")
```

[image]